# Killing a geoprocessing tool without killing all of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arctoolbox, geoprocessing-framework, layer-to-kml

When I try to open a geoprocessing tool (typically Layer to KML), the window frequently freezes, especially if I alt-tab away from the map.

I'd like to just kill that window, without killing all of ArcMap and forcing me to re-open it (which often takes several minutes). But, in Task Manager, there is no "Layer to KML" window, and shutting down any Arc-related processes (other than ArcMap) doesn't help.

Is there a way to do this? Note that I have not actually started running the tool-- I have just opened the window.

[image]

Comment: Can you go to `C:\Users\%user_profile%\AppData\Local\ESRI` and look around? Are there any error reports being created when you attempt to open the tool? The fact that it stalls before you even run it suggests a bigger problem than just how you close the window.

Comment: Simply, no.you cannot kill a tool window without killing all of ArcMap. You may want to update your question to fixing the issue, instead.

Comment: Are you on windows 10?  This happens to me all the time on 10.3, sent a bug report with a bunch of debug info to ESRI and they had no clue, just telling me to use the latest version

Comment: I checked "layer to kml" bugs and there's nothing listed for it hanging/crashing before the tool is fully open (for specific datasets or data types, yes).

Comment: Just to clarify, I've already tried to fix the bug that causes geoprocessing tools to stall. I've posted here, I've posted on GeoNet, and I've contacted the ESRI support team for my department. I appear to be the only one with this issue and nothing they suggested (deleting my user profile, re-installing ArcMap, etc) has worked, so I've just given up for now, and decided i should look into killing the process instead. Sorry for not clarifying that in the beginning.

Comment: @mikewatt when you say "this happens to me all the time" do you mean the geoprocessing tools stalling, or the inability to kill the tool window without killing all of ArcMap?

Comment: The former, there's no way to recover from the freeze AFAIK.  I also fresh-reinstalled to no avail.

Comment: @mikewatt wow, I've been working on this for a year and have literally never found anyone that had this bug. So weird! I hope this question turns up in Google for other folks who have this problem as well.